# Rotate icon ic_drawer in NavigationDrawer

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to turn 180 degrees icon `ic_drawer` in `NavigationDrawer` after clicking on the `drop-down menu`?

Currently, after expanding the Menu icon animates to the left - I would like to animating to the right (or the other way around than it is).

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use Toolbar which is introduced in support 21+

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mtoolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/primary" />
```

also add dependencies in your project .

The last thing to use ActionBarDrawerToggle  in your class.

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle  mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this, 
mDrawerLayout,mToolbar,"Drawer opentitle","Drawer closetitle");
```

Constructor's parameter need toolbar object ,so you have to use Toolbar.

check this out [ToolBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html)

Comment: Do I have to use this Toolbar? I can not use what I already have - NavigationDrawer? It's just a change of animation icons to make it the other way around.

Comment: hey ,if you want your icon to rotate then you have to use toolbar to animate icon .and might be using ActionBarActivity which is deprecated in sdk 21.

Comment: ActionBarToggle is the method used for Drawericon rotation animation that want and ActionBarToggle class has constructor whose arguments/parameters need toolbar to show Drawericon